# Django -- what is the error I am making in this simple view?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Here is my view.  I am trying to simply display a table with the http meta data.

```
def display_request_meta_data(request):
    meta_data = request.META.items()
    meta_data.sort()
    for x, y in meta_data:  # output of this loop pasted below
        print x, y
    t = get_template('http_meta_data_table.html')
    html = t.render(Context(meta_data)) # I don't understand how to write this line correctly.
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Here is what http_meta_data_table.html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTTP Meta Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {% for key, value in meta_data %}
            <tr><td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

The loop that prints x, y returns the following (truncated, because there is a bunch of it):

```
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render /tmp/launch-SvFjVB/Render
COLORFGBG 7;0
COMMAND_MODE unix2003
CONTENT_LENGTH 
CONTENT_TYPE text/plain
CSRF_COOKIE de982574e125805e307091fcd3f25d2e
DISPLAY /tmp/launch-d6usP9/org.x:0
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
EDITOR mate -w
GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1
HOME /Users/me
etc...
```

Comment: some tips: show us the error/stacktrace you got and look at the render_to_response shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` expects a dictionary, mapping keys to values. By calling `items()`, you got a list of tuples instead:

```
[('Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render', '/tmp/launch-SvFjVB/Render'), ...]
```

Even if you turned this back into a dict (which will lose the ordering), you still cannot use it as a context, because the template doesn't know a priori what keys are contained in it. Instead, pass `meta_data` as a value *inside* the dict:

```
html = t.render(Context({'meta_data': meta_data}))
```

Now saying `meta_data` in your template will call up the value associated with the key `meta_data`, which is a list, so your `for` tag will iterate over that list.

Comment: Thank you.  This explanation enabled me to see the light.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, we use `render_to_response` because it's slightly simpler.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

```
return render_to_response( 'http_meta_data_table.html',
    { 'meta': request.META },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

If you want to do it in separate steps, then you need to consider the following:

A Context is built from a dictionary.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects

The `request.META` already is a dictionary.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

You can do this

```
html = t.render(Context(meta=request.META))
```

In your template, you can display it with this

```
{% for k in meta %}
    <li><tt>{{k}}</tt> {{meta.k}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried `html = t.render(Context(request.META))` but I end up with an empty table in my resulting html page.  I think it is because my template doesn't know what the keys in the request.META dictionary are.

Comment: @Deonomo: I'll revise the answer to provide a suggestion on how you might approach this.  However, it's helpful to read the Django code that provides the error pages; since that appears to be what you're tying to mimic.